# Ant won't "run" Jasper Reports

Tags: apache, ant, jasper-reports, report, java

I recently set up `Jasper Reports`, `Apache Ant`, and `JDK` on my server. I followed a book. I put `jasper` and `ant` in the home directory and the opt directory. I did a little bit of conf editing as well. The last set it to get `ant` to run `Jasper Reports`, so I type `"ant runServer"` in the hsqldb directory and get `"ant: command not found".` :[

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually see these messages when `ant` executable is not on the run [path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28variable%29). The easiest workaround (it does not depend on the OS you use) is to execute it like this:

```
/path/to/ant runServer
```

Comment: Hi, I'm on Linux.

/opt/apache-ant-1.8.2 ant runServer
-bash: /opt/apache-ant-1.8.2: is a directory
Any other ideas? Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: Hmm... I think you did not understand. When you type `ant runServer` OS does not know where to find ant executable file. So to run it you will have to provide full path to its executable. In your case I suppose it is `/opt/apache-ant-1.8.2/ant runServer` or maybe `/opt/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant runServer`.

Comment: /opt/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant runServer
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

:[ - At least I got that! What is the next step you think?

Comment: Well, Ant always executes build script that are XML files. By default it tries to execute file named `build.xml` but in your case there is no such file. You can specify another file using `-f` parameter. Example: `/opt/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant -f file.xml runServer`. So your next step is to find this build file.

Comment: I changed it so it goes /opt/jasper/build.xml and did a run Server, it says permission denied. I am root. I also did the PATH correctly, i just didn't spell out all of the jasperreports-x-x-x stuff. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Usually when Ant fails it shows a line number from `build.xml` that indicates the line it was executing when failed. Looking at this line may give a clue. If Ant build was not started at all, then it is probably filesystem permissions issue.

Comment: okay, there is a sample report in jasper, it has a build.xml. I gave it 777 and got an error on line one of the build.xml file - I have no clue from here.

Comment: I suggest you either update or create a new question with the relevant code from `build.xml` and any other relevant sources.